# Android app to display whether a specific phone # called you before

Tags: android, phone

I'm looking for Android app with the following requirements:

- Gets launched when you have an incoming call (ideally, BEFORE you pick up!)
- Checks if the number is in your address book
- If it is not in address book; checks your call log, and displays how many calls you got from that number previously (total count, or some sort of frequency per time period, and/or last call time).

I don't really care about mechanics/GUI, it can be a notification, a balloon pop-up, something that integrates into "pick up the call" screens on either lockscreen or the dialer.

Comment: How easy should it be to configure? [Tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) can do all that, and you're just scratching on its surface with it. But it's rather complex. "Too complex" for most people, until they've spent 2..3 days getting into its boots. Acceptable? Or maybe you need to narrow down your requirements? ;)

Comment: @Izzy - Tasker is quite acceptable, BUT only if the answer gives usable enough instructions on how to configure to do EXACTLY what's asked (not so much because I'm lazy, but because I'm almost not familiar with Tasker and won't be able to evaluate if it can or cannot do what I require). However, if there's a Tasker answer and a dedicated easy to setup app; I will probably choose the latter as accepted answer :)

Comment: I'm afraid for an exact how-to and step-by-step guide I'm lacking the time, as I didn't use these specific features of Tasker yet (I'm using Tasker for years, but for different things). So all I could do is give some pointers to get you started, sorry. // Let's wait for other answers popping up. If there's a direct/easy solution, you might either prefer that. Ping me in chat if there wasn't anything until Monday ;)

Comment: @Izzy - will try. I'm surprised that tasker can grep through call logs; the rest of it should suffice with a pointer to existing tutorials ("how to trigger tasker task on incoming call", "how to display a tasker message in Notification")

Comment: To be honest, that's the only part I'm not *sure* of, and need to check. It has the permission to access them, and some addons and/or root powers given, that should be possible. See [AutoContacts](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.joaomgcd.autocontacts) for an example of what I had in mind here.

Comment: @Izzy: *ping*, just in case you are interested in providing an answer now :)

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not aware of any tool doing so by default, it can be achieved using **[Tasker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)** – the ultimative automation tool on Android. A detailed description of available commands etc. can be found in its [UserGuide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/).

Basically, *Tasker* works with Profiles, which are a combination of conditions and tasks – so you define which conditions should be matched, and what tasks to execute in that case. A raw example (just the concept) for your case could look like this:

- **Condition:** Event → Phone Ringing
- **Task:** (Display details)

Details depend on what's available. Here *Tasker* offers different details. You could have it open your call logs:

> **Call Log:**
>   Show the Call Log tab of the standard Android contacts application.

or use any of the available variables:

> **Call Name / Number/ Date / Time (In)** (dynamic, monitored)
>   `%CNAME / %CNUM / %CDATE / %CTIME`
>   The caller name, number, date and time of the current (if a call is in progress) or last call received.
>   Caller number is 0 if it's unknown.
>   Caller name is ? if it's unknown (probably because the caller number was blocked) and set to the caller number if the contact couldn't be looked up. It's unavailable on Android versions prior to 2.0.

There are different methods of notifications available, such as

- **Flash:** Flash a message up.
- **Notify:** Show a notification on the top bar.
- **Notify LED:** Show a notification on the top bar and flash an LED.
- **Notify Sound:** Show a notification on the top bar and play a sound.
- **Notify Vibrate:** Show a notification on the top bar and vibrate.
- **Set Tasker Icon:** Set the icon for Tasker's permanent notification in the status bar.
- **Vibrate On Notify:** Whether to vibrate with a system notification.

Some things can be combined, of course – and there are more possibilities you can investigate.

---

There might be additional options with other apps you can e.g. find in my app lists on [Various Contact and Phone Tools](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various) (specifically, in the section [Various caller tools](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_100)). There's e.g. **[Call Actions](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.movinapp.callactions)** which sounds promising concerning your requirements. Furthermore, on *F-Droid* you can find **[CallerDetails](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.wordpress.sarfraznawaz.callerdetails)** which sounds like a good match:

> Show contact details saved against a contact such as organization, email, address, note, etc in a toast message whenever there is an incoming call. If you have not set these fields for a contact, toast will not be shown.

I have not tried any of the last two apps, which is why I recommended *Tasker* in the first place – which is an app I'm using for years already, and am pretty happy with. Regular updates, runs stable. Just requires a little time to get used to, but it's definitely worth it!